# ionic offline app syncing

Tags: ionic3, couchdb, pouchdb, offline-mode

I've used a basic ionic3 camera module app for storing image information along with the image in localstorage while offline and the data should be syncing with the online couchdb datastorage when the user goes online which is not actually happening. There are no errors shown while running the app in cli.

I've followed these websites:

http://masteringionic.com/blog/2016-12-10-using-pouchdb-with-ionic-part-1/?s=2016-12-10-using-pouchdb-with-ionic-part-1/

http://masteringionic.com/blog/2016-12-11-using-pouchdb-with-ionic-part-2/

http://masteringionic.com/blog/2016-12-22-online-and-offline-syncing-of-data-in-ionic-using-pouchdb-couchdb/

this is the database.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';


@Injectable()
export class Database {

 private _DB : any;
 private success : boolean = true;
 private _remoteDB : any;
 private _syncOpts : any;

  constructor(public http : Http,
public alertCtrl : AlertController)
{
this.initialiseDB();
}



initialiseDB()
{
this._DB = new PouchDB('trees');
this._remoteDB = 'http://172.17.4.161:5984/dendronym';
this._syncOpts = { live : true,
retry : true,
continuous : true };
this._DB.sync(this._remoteDB, this._syncOpts)
.on('change', (info) =>
{
console.log('Handling syncing change');
console.dir(info);
})
.on('paused', (info) =>
{
console.log('Handling syncing pause');
console.dir(info);
})
.on('active', (info) =>
{
console.log('Handling syncing resumption');
console.dir(info);
})
.on('denied', (err) =>
{
console.log('Handling syncing denied');
console.dir(err);
})
.on('complete', (info) =>
{
console.log('Handling syncing complete');
console.dir(info);
})
.on('error', (err)=>
{
console.log('Handling syncing error');
console.dir(err);
});

}

handleSyncing()
{
this._DB.changes({
since : 'now',
live : true,
include_docs : true,
attachments : true
})
.on('change', (change) =>
{
// handle change
console.log('Handling change');
console.dir(change);
 })
 .on('complete', (info) =>
 {
 // changes() was canceled
 console.log('Changes complete');
 console.dir(info);
 })
  .on('error', (err) =>
 {
  console.log('Changes error');
  console.log(err);
  });
  }


  addTree(species, note, image)
  {
var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString(),
 base64String = image.substring(23),
tree = {
_id : timeStamp,
species : species,
note : note,
_attachments : {
"species.jpg" : {
content_type : 'image/jpeg',
data : base64String
}
}
};

return new Promise(resolve =>
{
this._DB.put(tree).catch((err) =>
{
console.log('error is: ' + err);
this.success = false;

});

if(this.success)
{
this.handleSyncing();
resolve(true);
}
});
}



updateTree(id, species, note, image, revision)
{
var base64String = image.substring(23),
tree = {
_id : id,
_rev : revision,
species : species,
note : note,
_attachments: {
"species.jpg" : {
content_type : 'image/jpeg',
data : base64String
}
}
};

return new Promise(resolve =>
{
this._DB.put(tree)
.catch((err) =>
{
console.log('error is: ' + err);
this.success = false;
});

if(this.success)
{
 this.handleSyncing();
 resolve(true);
}
});
}



 retrieveTree(id)
{
return new Promise(resolve =>
{
this._DB.get(id, {attachments: true})
.then((doc)=>
{
var item = [],
dataURIPrefix = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,',
attachment;

if(doc._attachments)
{
attachment = doc._attachments["species.jpg"].data;
}
else
{
console.log("we do NOT have attachments");
}



item.push(
{
id : id,
rev : doc._rev,
species : doc.species,
note : doc.note,
image : dataURIPrefix + attachment
});
resolve(item);
})
});
}




retrieveTrees()
{
return new Promise(resolve =>
{
this._DB.allDocs({include_docs: true, descending: true, attachments:                                                                  
true}, function(err, doc)
{
let k,
items = [],
row = doc.rows;

for(k in row)
{
 var item = row[k].doc,
 dataURIPrefix = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,',
 attachment;

if(item._attachments)
{
attachment = dataURIPrefix + item._attachments["species.jpg"].data;
}

else
{
console.log("we do NOT have attachments");
}

items.push(
{
id : item._id,
rev : item._rev,
species : item.species,
note : item.note,
image : attachment
});
}
resolve(items);
});
});
}



removeTree(id, rev)
{
return new Promise(resolve =>
{
var tree = { _id: id, _rev: rev };

this._DB.remove(tree)
.catch((err) =>
{
console.log('error is: ' + err);
this.success = false;
});

if(this.success)
{
resolve(true);
}
});
}



errorHandler(err)
{
let headsUp = this.alertCtrl.create({
title: 'Heads Up!',
subTitle: err,
buttons: ['Got It!']
});

headsUp.present();
}


}
```

Comment: Readers would need an [mcve] to be able to offer the best support here, I think. Would you show what code/config you have?

Comment: just added the code

Comment: Great! Have you done any debugging on it, such as looking at intermediate values with `console.log`, or examining network operations to see if they connect and send data? What specific lines should readers be looking at?

Comment: (If you can add some indentation to your code, in your own work and not just here, that will help both you and your readers).